# Powershell not continuing/not catching/not trapping

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch, break, continue

I am trying to speed up a program i've written to make copies of images in a new folder. I've gotten it to work when they all happen to have a standardized name, such as EA101, EA102, ect.

I'm fairly new to Powershell but am familiar with programming otherwise.
The issue I am dealing with arises when dealing with unique names, such as EA101-AG, or EA105-ST, ect. Here is my code:

```
$variations = @("-1212W",
"-1216M",
"-1216W",
"-1818W",
"-1824M",
"-1824W",
"-2424W",
"-912M",
"-912W",
"-COAST",
"-MAG",
"-MBC",
"-MSWD",
"-ORN",
"-POST",
"-SWD",
"-TAG",
"-BMKR",
"-PIN",
"-KEY",
"-28W",
"-416W",
"-624W",
"-832W",

"-33BLK",
"-77BLK",
"-46BLK",
"-57BLK",
"-659BLK",
"-1212BLK",
"-1818BLK",
"-2424BLK",
"-912BLK",
"-1216BLK",
"-1824BLK",
"-630W",
"-630M")


foreach($n in 1..9){
   
   Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\JunkFiles\PARK10$n.jpg" 
    trap{
    continue;
    }

    
    foreach($m in 1..38) {
        $v = $variations[$m]
        Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\NewFiles\PARK10$n$v.jpg"
      
    }
}
foreach($n in 10..99){

    Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK1$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\JunkFiles\PARK1$n.jpg"
   
    foreach($m in 1..38){
        $v = $variations[$m]
        Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK1$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\NewFiles\PARK1$n$v.jpg"
       catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {break}
}
}

foreach($n in 200..999){

    Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\JunkFiles\PARK$n.jpg"
  
    
    foreach($m in 1..38){
        $v = $variations[$m]
        Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\NewFiles\PARK$n$v.jpg"
       
}
}
```

I have attempted to implement traps, breaks, continues, and try/catches to skip instances where the program runs into a name that is not standardized. I have another script written to handle those. The issue is, the script *REALLY* does not want to stop running through the entire loop and attempt to make 38 copies of a file that does not exist. Considering there are nearly 500 files with the same naming standard, its taking way too long to run. I could run it anyhow but I am much more interested in learning how exactly Powershell is just ignoring these lines to get it to stop. I have had one setup sort of work, where Powershell only ran through the inner loop once:

```
foreach($n in 1..9){
   
   Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\JunkFiles\PARK10$n.jpg" 
    trap{
    continue;
    }

    
    foreach($m in 1..38) {
        $v = $variations[$m]
        Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\NewFiles\PARK10$n$v.jpg"
        trap{break;}
        catch{break;} # this could also be continue, didnt make a difference...
    }
}
```

This didn't work for me, however, because on instances where it didn't need to break, it broke after running through the loop only once.

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of your script to catch terminating errors.

Comment: And yes, you want `continue` instead of `break` at your `catch` block.

Comment: That $ErrorActionPreference line worked like a charm. Goes to show what i know about powershell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statements act on *terminating* errors only, which your code - at least with the default `$ErrorActionPreference` value of `'Continue'` - does *not* produce.

The more flexible *alternative* construct for catching terminating errors is a [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement:

- Such a statement allows more fine-grained control, whereas `trap` applies to the entire enclosing scope; in practice, `trap` is rarely used (anymore).

Use `trap` OR `try` / `catch`, and preferably use the latter.
If you do, you need a `try` clause too - you cannot just use `catch`.

Either way, in order for your code to produce *terminating* errors, you must promote the *non*-terminating errors that your `Copy-Item` commands produce to *terminating* ones, using one of the following methods:

- To automatically promote non-terminating errors to terminating ones *scope-wide*, use [`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) at the top of the scope, as suggested by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).
- Alternatively, selectively perform this promotion by passing [`-ErrorAction Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) to individual cmdlet calls.

Applied to your last code snippet:

```
# Promote all non-terminating errors to (script-)terminating ones.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

foreach($n in 1..9){
   
    try {
      Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\JunkFiles\PARK10$n.jpg" 
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
      continue # continue with the enclosing `foreach` loop 
    }
    
    foreach($m in 1..38) {
        $v = $variations[$m]
        try {
          Copy-Item "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\PARK10$n.jpg" -Destination "C:\Design Images for Web\PARK\NewFiles\PARK10$n$v.jpg"
        } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
          continue # continue with the enclosing `foreach` loop 
        }
    }
}
```